# DocView mode doesn't show pdf

Tags: pdf, emacs

I read in the manual "Document Viewing" page that DocView mode shows pdf files (since version 23, I found on the Internet), but my version 26 does not. It opens pdf documents always in Fundamental mode. I try to enable DocView mode with "M-x doc-view-mode", getting "Type C-c C-c to toggle between editing or viewing the document" in minibuffer and that is all. C-c C-c does nothing.
What's the matter?
Emacs v.26 on El Capitan OSX not in a shell window, in GUI.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc-view documentation:

> doc-view.el requires GNU Emacs 22.1 or newer. You also need Ghostscript, dvipdf (comes with Ghostscript) or dvipdfm (comes with teTeX or TeXLive) and pdftotext, which comes with xpdf (http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) or poppler (http://poppler.freedesktop.org/).

So make sure to install them (e.g. via Homebrew) first.

Then, add `/usr/local/bin` value to `exec-path variable, as suggested by user phils in [response](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64380/doc-view-mode-for-pdfs-not-working) at Thain's message.
Fantastic Emacs!

Comment: Doesn‘t this also require some tools to be installed in /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: There is Ghostscript: /usr/local/bin/gs; it is the already installed in OS X 10.11.6

Comment: In an standard macOS install, *nothing* is installed in `/usr/local/bin` (it's empty by default).

Comment: Have you installed [Emacs For Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com/)? I have a lot of file in /usr/local/bin/, some from bbedit, wireshark and so on.

Comment: Sure, so do I. But as written, your answer doesn‘t mention any need to install additional software (and which one). Just adding something to PATH will not solve the issue described in the question.

Comment: You're right, I wrongly assumed that the same software that I use is being used. I beg your pardon, please.

Comment: No problem, but maybe you can add the name of the required binaries to the answer so it becomes more useful to future visitors?

Comment: I downloaded Emacs For Mac OS X (version 26.3), at the link above, installed it and added the path as indicated by phils. That's all.

Comment: The Emacs For Mac OS X download doesn't include Ghostscript, dvipdf, pdftotext, all of them are required for DocView mode. I copied the corresponding lines from the answer you already link to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142850/discussion-between-marcello-and-nohillside).